# Precedence of parentheses between post-fix and pre-fix in C

Tags: c, operators

The [C Operator Preference Table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) notes the higher precedence of `()`.

Code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int temp=2;
    (temp += 23)++;    //Statement 1
    ++(temp += 23);    //Statement 2
    printf("%d",temp);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is while parentheses has higher precedence than pre-fix operator in Statement 2 why there's an error.
In Statement 1 both has same precedence but order of evaluation is from left to right. Still the same error.
Third doubt: operator += has much lower precedence, then why it's causing error.

```
error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

Comment: Any reason why you need this sort of convoluted code?

Comment: @Laurent : no specific reasons. Just checking out my own skills on confusing topics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `lvalue` is a value that some other value can be assigned to (because it is on the left side of the assignment operator). `(temp += 23)` is a `rvalue`. Nothing can be assigned to it.

Comment: I thought temp += 23 should be equal to temp = temp + 23. But now seems without semicolon(;) this is not equal. Am I right?

Comment: Both are equivalent; neither is an lvalue. You cannot assign to the expression `temp = temp + 23` because it only refers to a value not a storage location.

Comment: Yes but you also can't do `(temp = temp + 23) = 5`, so `(temp = temp + 23)` is a `rvalue`. They are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Something else I'd like to add, is that it looks like you're trying to **modify a value more than once in an expression**. That's **undefined behavior** according to C99 standard 6.5(2).

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
> modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value
> shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.

And footnote 71) shows the example:

> This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
>
> ```
> i = ++i + 1;
>
> a[i++] = i;
> ```
>
> while allowing
>
> ```
> i = i + 1;
>
> a[i] = i;
> ```